# New folder being created in FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I'm experiencing a very strange problem.

I have a WordPress site installed in a /wp directory, but the site address is set to the root domain. Within this installation there is a page called store, which sits at /store (due to the site address setup within WP).

However, a couple of times now, a new folder called /store has been created in the root directory. I'm the only one with FTP access and I have not created this folder.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be happening? I've never seen anything like this before. Could it be generated by a plugin? A permalink issue? It doesn't sound likely to me, but those are the only explanations I can think of.

The site in question is hillaryreynoldsband.com.

Comment: WordPress doesn't do this by default. It's probably caused by the store plugin. Why would it be created, though? No idea. Plugins should not modify files outside of wp-content. It's bad practice.

Comment: I know. It shouldn't be happening and doesn't happen on any other site that I've used the plugin on. Plus, the store plugin itself doesn't create pages or posts -- it's simply a way for them to accept PayPal payments on the site (the Ultra Simple PayPal Shopping Cart). So I really have no idea what's causing it to happen - but it's happened twice within the past week now.

Comment: I had this problem once, /blog directory kept being created, turned out to be an old subdomain i had set up at blog.domain.com, might be worth checking this as when I visit store.hillaryreynoldsband.com I get a 500 internal error

Comment: Thanks @DavidAlsbright - I'm going to see if I can get the domain account logins and take a look. That certainly sounds like the most logical explanation, and I hope that's what it is! I'll let you know.

Comment: Looks like you've removed the sub-domain in question, did it solve the issue?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Hey David - yes, it appears to have! I wanted to wait a few days to see if it re-appeared but after removing the subdomain, everything appears to be working fine now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting my comment as an answer in case anyone else encounters the same issue*

An old or incorrectly configured sub-domain can cause seemingly random folders to be created in the Wordpress directory, usually removing or re-configuring the sub-domain will fix the issue.